# Issues calculating simple integral in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, integral

I want to calculate the following integral with Matlab:

> integral x*sin(3x)*e^(x^3) dx from bound 1 to 5.

Use following commands, but not answer my integral.

> > syms x
> >
> > f=x*sin(3*x)*exp(x^3);
> >
> > int (x*sin(3*x)*exp(x^3),x,1,5)

where part of my code is wrong? anyone can help me?

Comment: Why is it wrong? errors? you dont like the output?

Comment: @AnderBiguri the output is ans =
 
int(x*sin(3*x)*exp(x^3), x, 1, 5)

Comment: My output includes `Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.` Maybe there's no explicit integral. That `x^3` exponent seems to be difficult to tackle

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. Maybe the integral just does not exist. However, you can integrate numerically! `x=1:0.1:5; f=x.*sin(3*x).*exp(x.^3); trapz(x,f);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure is correct. The problem is that Matlab doesn't know an explicit form for the primitive function. It produces the warning

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found
```

If you change `x^3` to `x`, for example, there is an explicit integral (which can probably be found [integrating by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), as usual with products of exponential and trigonometric functions):

```
>> syms x
>> int(x*sin(3*x)*exp(x),x,1,5)
ans =
(exp(1)*(12*cos(3) - 9*sin(3)))/50 - (exp(5)*(72*cos(15) - 29*sin(15)))/50
```